# Global calendars in MS-Project?

Tags: ms-project

If I replace a calendar in the Global.MPT file, will this calendar update all the other projects that are using it?

Suppose I make the following steps:

1. Copy a calendar to Global.MPT file.
2. Create a new project file and start using the calendar I just copied in  point 1.
3. Then, in another project, I made changes to the calendar. So I replace the one that was in the Global.MPT file (point 1).

Will the calendar get updated on all projects that are using it, for example the file mentioned in the point 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  You need to copy the modified calendar from global.mpt to replace the calendar in each project file.